# Convert To Dictionary needs to have a Node<T> for key

Tags: c#

```
public Dictionary<Node<T>, IList<Node<T>>> FlattenedMap { get; private set; }
private List<Node<T>> _dependencies; (note: these T instances have a NodeId and related ParentNodeId properties in it to work with)
```

.... more code, then:

```
public void CreateFlattenedMap()
{
    var groups = _dependencies.GroupBy(d => d.ParentId); // attempt to groupy the list by ParentNodeId

    var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList()); // attempt to flatten out each pair of parent Node<T> instances with their corresponding Parent Node<T>.Children list

    FlattenedMap = dictionary;
}
```

I'm trying to convert the groups to a dictionary but I don't want the key to be an Id. Because my FlattenedMap has a key of Node so not sure how to do the `ToDictionary` and have the key be the d, not d.Key basically to make this assignment happy.

So the problem is here: `FlattenedMap = dictionary;` as the dictionary ends up being `<int, List<Node<T>>>` instead of what I want which is `<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>` to satisfy how I want my dictionary formed via the property as the end result.

UPDATE

So what I've tried to do but doesn't work with my pseudo coded below is since d is type T and the dictionary really needs Node as the key, not d.Key (not T.Key) I tried to do something like this:

```
var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(d => new Node<T>(d), d => d.ToList());
```

actually now that I think about it, the List needs to not be `List<d>` or `IList<d>` but `List<Node<T>(d)>` or list of `<Node<d>>` (remember that T is an instance of d and Node expects any instance that has implemented INode which d has for sure).

so really that ToDictionary is creating this:  `<d.Key, List<d>>` so you end up with `(<int, List<d>)` which is not what my final dictionary expects.

somehow I need to take the d and convert it to Node on the fly in that ToDictionary so I end up with Dictionary>...hope I'm stating this right but you can get the sense of what I'm trying to say hopefully.

**UPDATE**

so tried something different in that I first converted my _dependencies to all Node instances to try to make this easier to work with or make it work in my CreateFlattenedMap()

Sow now, I'm trying that GroupBy on a list of IList> after I cycled the original dependencylist and converted each of them to a Node (in other words Node(d)) first.

So now, though same problem (and here is a more complete picture of my class for you):

```
   public class Tree<T> where T : INode
    {
        private readonly IList<T> _sourceDependencies;
        private readonly List<Node<T>> _nodeDependencies;

        public Node<T> RootNode { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Node<T>, IList<Node<T>>> FlattenedMap { get; private set; }

         public Tree(T rootNode, IList<T> dependencies )
        {
            RootNode = new Node<T>(rootNode); //convert the custom type to Node<T> first so we can work with it
            _sourceDependencies = dependencies;
            _nodeDependencies = ConvertListToNodes(_sourceDependencies);

            FlattenedMap();
        }

        private List<Node<T>> ConvertListToNodes(IList<T> listToConvert)
        {
            List<Node<T>> nodeList = _sourceDependencies.Select(sourceNode => new Node<T>(sourceNode)).ToList();
        }


       public void CreateFlattenedMap()
        {
            var parentGroups = _nodeDependencies.GroupBy(d => d.ParentNodeId);

            var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(d => new Node<T>(d), d => d.ToList());

            FlattenedMap = dictionary;
        }
```

Comment: `var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(d => d, d => d.ToList());` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: no, d is not of type Node<T>, it's just T

Comment: How you define your node<T>?

Comment: so I really need to convert d to Node<T> so like Node<T>(d) on the fly for the key

Comment: Node<T> is another class that expects any type that implements my INode interface

Comment: so this list of dependencies is an IList<INode>.  Node<T> expects any type which implements INode as well.  So the dictionary I am trying to set this Group.ToDictionary is expecting type Node<T> not T (or not just INode) for example.

Comment: The GroupBy is showing this when I mouse over it: IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Node<T>>> IEnumerable<Node<T>>.GroupBy<Node<T>, int>(System.Func<Node<T>>, int>, keySelector)
not sure why it's saying int for the IGrouping key
when d is not an int
d is a Node<T>

Comment: `d` is a `Node<T>`, but you're grouping by `ParentId`, which I assume is an `int`.

Comment: yea I need to group by Node<T>.ParentId as Node<T> has both a NodeId and related ParentId.  If I group all the nodes by ParentId, that will easily allow me to hopefully get a list of related Child nodes per Parent node as every Node<T> has a List<T> of child nodes in a property.

Comment: But in the end I wanna be able to therefore shove each Parent Node<T> and related List<Node<T> children into a Dictionary.  So I figured group by ParentId, then now I can easily shove the ParentNode and ParentNode.Children into a dictionary

Comment: the whole goal of this is to take a list of dependencies, where those dependencies are of type Node<T> and have properties like NodeId, ParentNodeId, List<Node<T>> children and be able to create a dictoniary map of all parents and their related list of children.

Comment: Do all your nodes have a ParentNode property?

Comment: Might be helpful for you to post your Node<T> class, but I'm going to bed now...

Answer (score 1):

Would this do what you want?

```
var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(
    d => new Node<T>(d.Key), 
    d => d.ToList());
```

Comment: no because to create a new Node<T> it doesn't expect an Id.  It expects a custom type that implements INode which d does.  So I would think this would have worked but does not: var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(
    d => new Node<T>(d), 
    d => d.ToList());

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, why doesn't it work? Is there a compile-time error?

Comment: It probably isn't compiling because `d` in this case (since you have grouped it) is actually an `IGrouping<Node<T>, int>`

Comment: see my update in the original post, better code there for you to see what I tried lately.